# Angularjs/ Jquery animate on a new div

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate

I want to add an animation on a new div that i created after clicking on the save button. The animation works when the div exists already on the page (on an update) but it's not working on a new div :

```
$scope.save(bookId) = function {
  $scope.books.unshift(newBook);
  var bookDivContainer = $("#bookContainer-" + bookId);

  bookDivContainer.animate({ opacity: '0.4' }, "fast");
  bookDivContainer.animate({ opacity: '0.9' }, "slow");
}
```

There's a way to call animate on a new element just created ? something like .on ?

Thanks

Comment: Try using $timeout and then call the animate after you create new book.

Comment: $timeout worked for me :) thanks